# how to show the response body of a http request with dart?

Tags: curl, dart

i have a curl request :

```
curl \
  -F 'filename=@<IMAGE_PATH>' \
  -F 'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
  https://graph.facebook.com/v<API_VERSION>/act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/adimages
```

which i transformed into this request in dart:

```dart
final formData = {'filename': '@$path', 'access_token': ACCESS_TOKEN};

http.post(
  'https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/act_$AD_ACCOUNT_ID/adimages',
  body: formData,
).then((http.Response response) {
  if (response.statusCode == HttpStatus.ok) {
    print("success");
    // print(response.statusMessage);
    // print(response.headers);
    print(response.body);
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to create Ads.');
  }
```

i send correctly the request because i have an response type 200 but i would like to get the response body of this request. when i tried with the command **response.body** the result was **{} without anything inside**. so i want to know how i can show the response body knowing that curl request works and show informations when i try it in cmd prompt.  i precise i also tried to use Dio package for that but it returned me the same result (accolades without data inside).

here is the capture of the response in curl command:

[image]

Comment: What was the response you got from the curl command?

Comment: i have edited the question with the response of curl command @Abion47